# How do I return a table from a SQL query as a List in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, xamarin

I have a Xamarin app that connects to a SQL Server (*), and I want to insert the data from the SQL Server's tables into a local SQLite database. My approach is to execute a query like

```
select * from Table1
```

retrieve the results of the query as a `List`, then insert that `List` into my SQLite table. That said I'm very new at using `SqlClient`, so please share if there are better ways to do this. Thanks.

Edit: the smallest number of columns these tables have is 5. Don't know if that disqualifies Lists as the best option.

My code:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    string cs = @"connection string here";

    using (SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        sconn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlCommand aml = new SqlCommand("select * from Table1");
        reader = aml.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // get result of query as List somehow?
        }

        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<Table1>();

            if (conn.Query<Table1>("select * from Table1").Count() <= 0)
            {
                // insert the list object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(*) The app does not use a web service as the app is intended for onsite use only and will not be distributed publicly.

Comment: Check the examples in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8#examples) and have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024226/how-to-generate-liststring-from-sql-query) may help. Get the value from reader and add them to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better alternative way to do it more easier is to use a ORM like [dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper)

With the help of dapper, all you need to do is

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_sqlConnectionString))
{
    var results = connection.Query<YourTableModel>(query).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Note for anyone coming here in the future, you don't need a separate `SqlConnection` for each table; you can retrieve as many tables as you want in the one `using` directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from the SQL Server as DataTable or convert it to a list as you prefer.

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string connectionString, string tableName)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
string query = $'SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]';

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    a.Fill(t1);
}
return t1;
}
```

Then use this table or list returned from the above method to insert in the SQLite table.

```
string cs = @"Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=user;Password=password";


    DataTable table = GetDataTable(cs, "Table1");
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                    {
                       conn.CreateTable<Table1>();
                       if (conn.Query<Table1>("select * from Table1").Count() <= 0)
                          {
                              foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) 

                              {
                                //Access values of each row column      row["columnName"]
                                // insert the list object
                              }
                          }
                    }
```

Refer to this one:
[Inserting Data from SQL Server to Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904815/inserting-data-from-sql-server-to-sqlite)